# Which layer is responsible for flow control?

Tags: networking

I was reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) page at wikipedia and am confused to see that flow control is seen at three layers,

Under ***physical layer*** I see the link

> it may define the protocol for flow control.

Under  ***network layer*** I see the link

> ...This layer uses routers and switches to manage its traffic
>   (control flow control, error check, routing etc.) ...

Under ***transport layer*** I see the line

> .. The transport layer controls the reliability of a given link through flow control, segmentation/desegmentation, and e...

Now at which layer is the flow control generally implemented ? I can understand that it may vary under various circumstances, I read that too, but that is the most general case ? What would be a plain answer to the question *Which layer takes care of flow control ?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I learnt it in the ISO-OSI model:

- Physical layer is not responsible for flow control in general.
- Data link layer may provide flow control "on the wire".
- Network layer provides flow control between routers by [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Source_quench). The end terminals usually do not use the network layer barely. IP does not provide flow control.
- Transport layer, more specifically TCP provides flow control by a backtracking algorithm while UDP does not. TCP has various flow and congestion avoiding protocols, such as TCP Vegas.

As I get it: when routers have flow control problems, it is handled in the network layer, when end points have this problem, it's handled in the transport layer.

Answer (score 2):

Flow control is generally implemented on two layers Datalink Layer (Layer 2) and Transport Layer (Layer 4).

[Webopedia Link](http://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/OSI_Layers.asp)

[Wikipedia Link](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)